# Why adding proc_get_status() makes proc_close() to return -1?

Tags: php, process, exit, status, exit-code

- `proc_close()` returns `0`, if I do not write `proc_get_status()` function
- `proc_close()` returns `1`, if I write `proc_get_status()` before `proc_close()` function

**without calling `proc_get_status()` function**

code:

```
$descriptorspec = array(1 => array("pipe", "w"));
$process = proc_open('ls', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

//$ret_status = proc_get_status($process)['exitcode'];
//echo 'ret_status: ' . print_r($ret_status, true) . PHP_EOL;

$ret_process = proc_close($process);
echo 'ret_process: ' . print_r($ret_process, true) . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
hello_world.txt
ret_process: 0
```

**calling `proc_get_status()` function**

code:

```
$descriptorspec = array(1 => array("pipe", "w"));
$process = proc_open('ls', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

$ret_status = proc_get_status($process)['exitcode'];
echo 'ret_status: ' . print_r($ret_status, true) . PHP_EOL;

$ret_process = proc_close($process);
echo 'ret_process: ' . print_r($ret_process, true) . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
hello_world.txt
ret_status: 0
ret_process: -1
```

PHP version:

```
$ php -version
PHP 7.3.31-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2021 15:18:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.31, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.31-1~deb10u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**expected:** `proc_close()` to not depend on calling `proc_get_status()` and return `0` in both cases

Could anybody, please, explain what do I miss here?

Comment: Check out the comments in the manual, I there might be a race condition where not interacting with the process means `proc_close` might return before the process can complete, but that’s just a guess: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php#56798

Comment: @ChrisHaas `proc_get_status()` gives correct 'success' Exit status, and I can rely on that. But `proc_close()` reports failure for some reason. I've isolated the error to the simple code posted above. The output is always the same. Calling `proc_get_status()` makes `proc_close()` to report error for some reason...